# pandas: trouble getting mean using groupby, transform, eq

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get mean using groupby(apple and orange), eq, and transform, however, i got keyword error and 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'df' on both my attempts... Kindly advise on where i did wrong or are there other alternatives. Many thanks

```
df['mon_mean'] = df['day'].eq(mon).groupby(df['apple'], df['orange']).transform('mean')
df['tue_mean'] = df['day'].eq(tue).groupby(df['apple', 'orange']).transform('mean')
```

```
data = {'date':['mon','mon','tue', 'mon', 'tue'],
'apple':[1,2,3,8,9],
'orange':[10,20,29,21,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'apple', 'orange'])
```

Comment: Could you share us the entire code for this purpose, please? It'll be helpful to know how you create the data frame.

Comment: If grouping this way you need to supply a list of array-likes (in this case Series). So you'd do `.groupby([df['apple'], df['orange']])` (note the extra set of `[]` as compared to your first attempt)

Comment: @ zkan, sorry about it, l've added the necessary

Comment: What is your expected output? I think your attempts might be missing the mark a little. For each day, do you need the mean of the apple and orange column?

Comment: @ ALollz. that works. thanks